# A is $n\times n$ diagonalizable matrix and that A has only 2, ad 4 as its eigenvalues. Show that $A^2=6A-8I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

suppose A is $n\times n$ diagonalizable matrix and that A has only 2, ad 4 as its eigenvalues. How would you show that $A^2=6A-8I$

I've tried using eigenvectors but Im really stuck on showing this

Comment: Think about the minimal polynomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $k$ be the multiplicity of 2 as an eigenvalue, then $n-k$ is the multiplicity of 4.

Diagonalizing $A$, with $P$ as a transition matrix, yields:

$$D=\begin{bmatrix}
2  &        &        &        &        &    \\
   & \ddots &   &   &        &   \\
  &   &      2 &   &   &    \\
   &   &   &      4 &   &    \\
   &        &   &  & \ddots &   \\
  &        &        &       &        & 4
\end{bmatrix}
$$

With $k$ twos and $n-k$ fours.

Then $A^2$ is similar to (with the same transition matrix):
$$
D^2=\begin{bmatrix}
4  &        &        &        &        &    \\
   & \ddots &   &   &        &   \\
  &   &      4 &   &   &    \\
   &   &   &      16 &   &    \\
   &        &   &  & \ddots &   \\
  &        &        &       &        & 16
\end{bmatrix}$$

Since the identity matrix commutes with all matrices, it commutes with $P$ and we find that $6A-8I$ is also similar to $D^2$ (with the same transition matrix) because $2\times 6 -8=4$ and $4\times 6 -8 =16$.

In the end, we found, $PA^2P^{-1} = P(6A-8I)P^{-1}$. Since $P$ is invertible, $A^2 = 6A-8I$ holds.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $=(X-2)(X-4)=X^2-6X+8$, but since these are the only eigenvalues, you know that the characteristic polynomial is something like$(X-2)^k(X-4)^n$. From here, try Cayley-hamilton Cayley-Hamilton and a little algebra.